# How do you map a Dto to an existing object instance with nested objects using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, nested, automapper, dto

I have the following Dto and entity with a nested sub entity.

```
public class Dto
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string SubProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public SubEntity Sub { get; set; }
}

public class SubEntity
{
    public string SubProperty { get; set; }
}
```

How can I set up a mapping with **AutoMapper** that will allow me to update an existing instance of *Entity* with the values from a *Dto*.

I'm using `Mapper.Map(dto, entity)` to update an existing entity but when I try to map `Dto.SubProperty` to `Entity.Sub.SubProperty` I get an exception for *"must resolve to top-level member. Parameter name: lambdaExpression"*.

If I create a mapping from `Dto` to `SubEntity` using `FromMember` then `Entity.Sub` gets replaced with a new instance of `SubEntity` but that's not what I want. I just want it to update the properties of the existing instance of `SubEntity` on the `Sub` property of `Entity`.

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Can you show your current mapping definitions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved it by using a combination of the `ResolveUsing<T>()` method and implementing `IValueResolver` and the `ConvertUsing<T>()` method and implementing `ITypeConverter<TSource,TDestination>`.

Some of my mapping scenarios are more complicated than normal including bidirectional mapping and nested classes and nested collections. The above helped me to solve them.

---

### EDIT

As requested, I've included an example solution. This example is much simpler than the actual types I was dealing with.

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

namespace TestAutoMapperComplex
{
    public class Dto
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public string SubProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public SubEntity Sub { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubEntity
    {
        public string SubProperty { get; set; }
    }

    static class MapperConfig
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Dto, Entity>()
                .ForMember(entity => entity.Sub, memberOptions =>
                    memberOptions.MapFrom(dto => dto));
            Mapper.CreateMap<Dto, SubEntity>();
        }
    }

    static class MapperConfig2
    {
        private class MyResolver : IValueResolver
        {

            public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
            {
                var destinationSubEntity = ((Entity)source.Context.DestinationValue).Sub;

                Mapper.Map((Dto)source.Value, destinationSubEntity);

                return source.New(destinationSubEntity, typeof(SubEntity));
            }
        }

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Dto, Entity>()
                .ForMember(entity => entity.Sub, memberOptions =>
                    memberOptions.ResolveUsing<MyResolver>());
            Mapper.CreateMap<Dto, SubEntity>();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MapperConfig.Initialize();

            var dto = new Dto {Property = "Hello", SubProperty = "World"};
            var subEntity = new SubEntity {SubProperty = "Universe"};
            var entity = new Entity {Property = "Good bye", Sub = subEntity};

            Mapper.Map(dto, entity);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("entity.Property == {0}, entity.Sub.SubProperty == {1}",
                entity.Property, entity.Sub.SubProperty));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("entity.Sub == subEntity: {0}", 
                entity.Sub == subEntity));

        }
    }
}
```

If you run the example, which is using `MapperConfig`, you'll get the following output:

```
entity.Property == Hello, entity.Sub.SubProperty == World
entity.Sub == subEntity: False
```

The string properties all get updated as one would want them to, but `entity.Sub` gets replaced with a new instance of `SubEntity` which is no good for when you are wanting to update entities for an ORM that will be persisted to a database.

If you modify `Main` so that `MapperConfig2` is used instead, you'll still have the string properties updated as before, **but**, `entity.sub` still has the same instance of `SubEntity` that it had before. Running the example with `MapperConfig2` gives this output:

```
entity.Property == Hello, entity.Sub.SubProperty == World
entity.Sub == subEntity: True
```

The key difference in `MapperConfig2` is that `ResolveUsing` is used along with `MyResolver` to preserve the value of `entity.Sub`.

Comment: I' facing the same problem but can't figure out how to do it based on you own answer. Could you give me some hints? Thank you!