# Automapper : partial mapping

Tags: automapper

I am using Automapper to transfer data from objectA to objectB

```
classe ObjectA
{
   string Title;
   string Summary;
}

classe ObjectB
{
   string Title;
   string Summary;
   IAddress Address;
}
```

I created this kind of mapping between the two objects

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IObectA, IObjectB>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Title,           src => src.MapFrom(s => s.Title))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Summary,         src => src.MapFrom(s => s.Summary))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Address,         src => src.Ignore())
```

I create my ObjectB and fill all its properties including Address

When I call the mapper, I was expecting it to override Title and Summary and ignore Address

```
ObjectB = Mapper.Map<IObjectA, IObjectB>(objectA);
```

Actually,  it is throwing and exception for Address.

What am I doing wrong?

**[UPDATE]**
To express it differently, I have my objectB and I want to update part of it with data coming from ObjectA. When I say Ignore, I mean leave the data the way they already are

Comment: it might be useful to know what exception you received...

Comment: It seems you are doing everything wrong. Your code example shows the class definition for ObjectA twice. Later you say you fill ObjectB with all its properties, but in the last code snippet it shows you are trying to map objectA to objectB, not the other way around.

Comment: @JoDG, My Mistake. I updated my initial post.       
threw an exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'

Comment: I have no idea where the exception comes from. Your actual question seems to be identical to this one however: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672447/how-do-you-map-a-dto-to-an-existing-object-instance-with-nested-objects-using-aut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672447/how-do-you-map-a-dto-to-an-existing-object-instance-with-nested-objects-using-aut)

Comment: Yes, but it is very less complicated case
How to update an existing object instance using AutoMapper?

Comment: additionally to automapper you could use valueinjecter, with it this operation would be just ObjectB.InjectFrom(ObjectA) without any configuration at all

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the solution.

I just discovered that Map method has an overloaded version that excepts a pre-instantiated destination object.
Thanks to this [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20130124102758/http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/45/automapper---a-custom-type-converter-that-exposes-a-destination-value)

```
Mapper.Map<IObjectA, IObjectB>(objectA, ObjectB );
```

**@JoDG,** Thank you for your help

Comment: The article linked to does not exist anymore... :(

Comment: @noocyte : Archive.org has your back!  http://web.archive.org/web/20130124102758/http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/45/automapper---a-custom-type-converter-that-exposes-a-destination-value

Comment: just as a note, you shouldn't need to specify the types in <>

    Mapper.Map(objectA, ObjectB);

Should be enough